# C++/CX D'tor not called

Tags: c++, multithreading, windows-runtime, c++-cx, circular-reference

I created a `ref class Dispatcher` for our WinRT application that uses a thread from the `Windows::System::Threading::ThreadPool` to create sort of a message pump infrastructure. The `Dispatcher` must be inherited in order for the derived class have this mechanism.

The problem is that every class that derives from this base Dispatcher is not destructed (D'tor not called).

I isolated the problem and I think I have an understanding of what causes this issue, but I'm not sure how to solve this.

Here's some of the code that relates to the issue:

```
public delegate void FunctionDelegate();
ref class Dispatcher
{
protected private:
    Dispatcher()
    {   
        m_invocationHandle = CreateEvent(nullptr, FALSE, FALSE, nullptr);
        m_disposed = false;

        m_asyncThread = Windows::System::Threading::ThreadPool::RunAsync(
            ref new Windows::System::Threading::WorkItemHandler(
                [this](Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction^ operation)
        {
            while (m_disposed == false)
            {
                WaitForSingleObject(m_invocationHandle, INFINITE);
                //copy Pending Queue to Executing Queue
                //Run all handlers in Executing Queue and clear it
            }
        }));
    }

public:
    virtual ~Dispatcher()
    {
        m_disposed = true;
        SetEvent(m_invocationHandle);
        JoinInvocationThread();
        CleanUp(); //close handles etc...
    }

    void BeginInvoke(FunctionDelegate^ function)
    {
        PendingQueue->Append(function);
        SetEvent(m_invocationHandle);
    }
};
```

So, since this is a ref class its d'tor should be invoked when the ref count reaches 0, but since I pass `this` to the `WorkItemHandler` delegate, the thread holds a reference to the `Dispatcher` class, which causes a circular reference. Thus since the thread is infinitely waiting for a the `m_invocationHandle` event to be set, there is always a reference to `this` class which will never call its destructor (which should set the `m_invocationHandle` event and wait for the thread to complete).

I thought about using `Platform::WeakReference` but I will have to `Resolve` it to a `Dispatcher^` before callsing `WaitForSingleObject(...)` in order to get the `m_invocationHandle` which doesn't help since this will raise the ref count as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: @HansPassant I think you're missing the fact that the c'tor creates a thread from the thread pool which runs asynchronously...thus the c'tor does completes

Comment: Split into two objects. One is the public Dispatcher, which has a reference to the "real" dispatcher. When the public dispatcher is destructed, it tells the "real" dispatcher to clean up.

Comment: @RaymondChen, thanks for the suggestion, sounds simple and keeps the encapsulation I wanted. I actually solved this by passing references to the required members instead of passing `this`, but your suggestions sound "cleaner"

Answer (score 0):

Capture "this" as regular pointer rather than C++/CX pointer if you don't want it added. Just make sure that your function then ends before the destructor finishes:

```
Dispatcher()
{   
    m_invocationHandle = CreateEvent(nullptr, FALSE, FALSE, nullptr);
    m_disposed = false;
    IInspectable* _this = reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(this);

    m_asyncThread = Windows::System::Threading::ThreadPool::RunAsync(
        ref new Windows::System::Threading::WorkItemHandler(
            [_this](Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction^ operation)
    {
            reinterpret_cast<Dispatcher^>(_this)->MyLoop();
    }));
}

void MyLoop()
{
    while (m_disposed == false)
    {
        WaitForSingleObject(m_invocationHandle, INFINITE);
        //copy Pending Queue to Executing Queue
        //Run all handlers in Executing Queue and clear it
    }
}
```

Comment: Um, no. The lambda will release `this` when it destructs, and now you have a double -release bug.